# Check if matlab handle is a figure handle

Tags: matlab, handle

How to check if a matlab handle is a handle of a figure or not ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To test for a figure handle without risking an error, you do the following:

```
isFigureHandle = ishandle(h) && strcmp(get(h,'type'),'figure')
```

Answer (score 5):

I know this post is old, but I thought I would contribute.

```
isgraphics(h,'figure')
```

this differentiates between subplots and plots

Comment: This only is available from 2014b onward.

Answer (score 1):

pretty obvious - look for `Type: 'figure'`

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [ishghandle](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ishghandle.html)(h) function

Comment: It does not distinguish between figure and subplot.